# ADFS SSO Sliding Expiration

Tags: single-sign-on, wif, adfs

After reading a few articles (like http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2010/06/16/warning-sliding-sessions-are-closer-than-they-appear/), I now have a sliding expiration built into my Application1. As long as I stay active in Application1, then, I won't have to re-log-in.

However, if I go to Application2 after my ADFS timeout, I will have to log in there. This may confuse my user, who will wonder why their SSO is not working.

Is there a way to refresh the ADFS token at the same time I refresh Application1's login timeout?

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?  I'm looking into using ADFS for a client and am struggling to find any info online about how sliding sessions would work across applications.

Comment: I have not, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

We have build a HttpModule that implements a sliding expiration accross all site. And the ADFS timeout is set to 480 minutes (8 hours) by default. We have increased this timeout to 12 hours. So as long the user is active he won't be asked for his credentials.

But no there's no way to refresh the ADFS token.